# Are Infinite Simplicial Complexes Hausdorff?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

This is my definition of an Infinite Simplicial Complex:

Let $V$ be an (infinite) set.

Let $\Sigma$ be a collection of finite nonempty subsets of $V$ such that:

$$ \forall v \in V \space \space \space\{v\} \in \Sigma \space \space$$ and $$ \forall t \in \Sigma \space \space \forall s \subset t \space \space s \neq \emptyset \implies s \in \Sigma $$

The Realization is produced this way:

For each $ \sigma \in \Sigma \space $ , associate the standard $ (|\sigma|  - 1)-simplex$ and label the vertices with the elements of $ \sigma $

Then form equivalence classes of sigma such that... (will add further detail in a bit)

Is the Realization necessarily Hausdorff?

EDIT: I think i have it now, the quotient topology gives us nice open sets to use

Comment: Yes, it is. All CW complexes are $T_4$, so they are Hausdorff.

Comment: thanks, but this is not very helpful to me. is there perhaps a "from the ground up" approach? how would i go about showing this. If CW are just a generalization then can we reduce a proof down?

Comment: @JC784: I think if you want have a precise proof (or at least a less informal hint) you should give a precise definition of your realization.

Comment: You can also show this "from the ground up". The idea is to inductively construct open saturated neigborhoods in all dimensions.

Comment: Ah ok, i had seen a proof which sounds a similar approach in Hatcher's book for  CW complexes; the notation and terminology confused me a bit

Comment: Yah, the idea is essentially the same. Hatcher proves it for disjoint closed sets. A direct proof with points in the simplicial complex is similar.

Comment: http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATapp.pdf

It's in here (pg 522) , but i am struggling, especially with the characteristic map

Comment: Do you understand how the open neighborhood $N_\epsilon(A)$ is built?

Comment: I understand the base case, then not really

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13299/discussion-between-jc784-and-stefan-hamcke)

Comment: I am trying to solve a similar problem - you said in your post that the quotient topology gives us nice open sets to use, what are these nice open sets? Thanks

Comment: I answered http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/705473/show-simplicial-complex-is-hausdorff today, have a look for a direct demonstration of the Hausdorff property without using the CW structure. How do you like to remain with your question here?