# Show simplicial complex is Hausdorff

Tags: general-topology, simplicial-stuff, separation-axioms

I have a simplicial complex $K$ and I need to show that its topological realisation $|K|$ is Hausdorff. And $K$ need not be finite.

I have very little idea on how to get started on this. Only that if $x,y \in |K|$, I need to find disjoint open sets containing $x$ and $y$. I also know $|K|$ is a quotient space formed by "glueing" simplices together along their faces, so I have the quotient collapsing map, $p: K \to |K|$ and so my open sets $U, V$ are open iff their pre-images under this map are open.

Any help on how to get started would be much appreciated.

Comment: Either the two points are contained in the same simplex, or they are not.

Comment: Would you mind expanding this a bit? I'm not quite sure how it helps? Thanks

Comment: What do you know about the topological properties of a simplex which might be relevant if it contains two points. If a simplex contains a point, how might you construct an open set containing the point which will help you?

Comment: Well a simplex is just a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ for some $n$ so it is Hausdorff? and so if you have two points in the same simplex you can certainly fit two open sets around them? And then if you have two points in different simplices you can fit open sets around them?

Comment: Try the interior of a simplex as an open set - taking care you have covered the $0$-dimensional case.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let $q:D\to|K|$ denote the quotient map, where $D$ is the disjoint union $\coprod_σ|\Delta_\sigma^n|$ of (the realizations of) all simplices in $K$. The quotient space consists of equivalence classes, and each class contains a unique point in the interior of some simplex, this is the point in the simplex of lowest dimension (We take the interior of $Δ^0$ to be $Δ^0$ itself). For the two classes, let $x,y$ denote these two points. In order to find disjoint open neighbourhood $N(x)$ and $N(y)$, let us construct disjoint saturated open sets in $D$.

For each simplex $\sigma$, we will find an open subset $U_σ$ of $\Delta_σ^n$ containing the set $[x]\capΔ_σ^n$ as well as the points identified with $U_\tau$ for each face $\tau$ of $σ$. Denote the union of all $U_σ$ for the $σ$ of dimension $\le n$ by $N^n(x)$
Start at dimension $0$: If $\{x\}$ is one $0$-simplex $σ$, let $N^0(x)=\sigma$, otherwise $N^o(x)=\emptyset$.
Now assume by induction that we have constructed the disjoint open saturated sets $N^n(x)$ and $N^n(y)$.

- Let $V_σ(x)$ and $V_σ(y)$ denote the sets of points in the faces of $Δ_σ^{n+1}$ which are identified with $N^n(x),N^n(y)$ respectively. Note that if $x\in\mathring{Δ_σ}$, then $N^n(x)$ is empty.
- If one of the $V_σ$ is non-empty, we can thicken it a bit by stretching it towards the barycenter of the simplex. These thickenings will remain disjoint.
- If $V_σ(x)$ is non-empty and $y\in\mathring{Δ_σ}$, then we can keep the thickening of $V_σ(x)$ small enough, so that it is disjoint to an open ball around $y$ within 
  $\mathring{Δ_σ}$
- If both $x$ and $y$ are in $\mathring{Δ_σ}$, then they have disjoint open balls within the interior of $σ$.

If we do this for every simplex of dimension $n+1$, we obtain disjoint open saturated sets in the disjoint union of all simplices of dimension $\le n+1$. This completes the induction.
In the end, $N(x):=\bigcup_n N^n(x)$ and $N(y):=\bigcup_n N^n(y)$ have disjoint open images in $|K|$.

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive answer! When you say that each equivalence class contains a unique point in the interior, does this mean that under the equivalence relation the whole interior of each simplex is identified?

Comment: @Wooster: No, not at all. Have a look at the relation which forms the space. If $\tau$ is a face of the $n$-simplex $\sigma$ (which means that $\tau$ is obtained by omitting the $i$-th vertex of $σ$, one usually writes $\tau=d_iσ$ in that case), then we identify a point $x\inΔ_\tau^{n-1}$ (the standard $n-1$-simplex which belongs to $\tau$) with its image under the embedding $D_i:Δ_\tau^{n-1}\hookrightarrowΔ_σ^n$. There is no way two points in the interior of single simplex could ever get identified.

Comment: A $2$-simplex is identified with a face (i.e. a subset of the boundary) of a $3$ simplex $σ$. So a point $x$ in the $3$-simplex is either in the interior of $σ$, or it is in the boundary $\partialσ$, in which case some point $x'$ in a $2$-simplex $\tau$ is identified with $x$. Repeating this step, $x'$ is either in the interior $\mathringΔ_\tau$, or it is the boundary, so it is identified with some $x''$ in some $1$-simplex.

Comment: This is a brilliant answer, and excellent explanations provided.

Answer (score 2):

I read the following solution in $\textit{Elements of Algebraic Topology}$ by Munkres.

If $x$ is a point of polyhedron $|K|$ (the topological space of simplicial complex), then $x$ is interior to exactly one simplex of $K$, whose vertices are (say) $a_0, \cdots, a_n$. Then 
$$
x= \sum_{i=0}^{n}t_ia_i
$$
where, $t_i>0 \; \forall i$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{n}t_i =1$. If $v$ is an arbitrary vertex of $K$, we define the $\textbf{barycentric coordinate} \; t_v(x)$ of $x$ w.r.t. $v$ as:
$$
t_{v}(x)={\displaystyle \left\{{\begin{array}{lr}0 \quad \text{ if } v \text{ is none of } \{a_0,\cdots,a_n \}  \\ t_i \quad \text{ if } v \text{ is one of } \{a_0,\cdots,a_n \} \text{ (say) } a_i \end{array}}  \right.}
$$

For a fixed $v$, the function $t_v(x)$ is continuous when restricted to a fixed simplex $\sigma $ of $K$, since either it is equal to $0$ on $\sigma$ or equals the barycentric coordinates $t_i(x)$ of $x$ w.r.t $\{a_0,\cdots,a_n \}$ ( which are continuous function of $x$). We use another result that a map $f : |K| \rightarrow X$ is continuous $\iff \; f|_{\sigma}$ is continous for each simplex $\sigma \in K$ (use the result $f^{-1}(C) \cap \sigma = (f|_{\sigma}) ^{-1}(C) $ for any closed set $C$ in $X$).

Hence, the function $t_v(x)$ is continuous on $K$.

$\textbf{|K| is Hausdorff:} $

Let $ x_0,x_1 (x_0 \neq x_1)$ be two points in $|K|$. There exist atleast one vertex $v$ in $K$ s.t. $t_v(x_0) \neq t_v(x_1)$. Now, we choose any real no. $r$ between these two. The set $\{x:t_{v}(x)<r \}$ and $\{x:t_{v}(x)> r \}$ are two open sets. (Why are these open? Since, range of the continuous function $t_v(x)$ is $[0,1)$, and $[0,r)$ and $(r,1)$ is open in $[0,1)$)

Answer (score 1):

Yet another approach...

I will call $|K|_d$ the metric space associated to $|K|$. Consider the function $\eta : |K| \rightarrow |K|_d$ defined to be $\eta(\alpha)=\alpha$ for $\alpha  \in |K|$.

By proving $\eta$ continuous, we show that every open set in $|K|_d$ is open in $|K|$, equivalently, the metric topology is coarser than the topology of $|K|$ (that is the final topology on $|K|$ with respect to the family of inclusions $inc_\sigma \colon |\sigma| \rightarrow |K|$). But $|K|_d$ is Hausdorff since it is a metric space, so $|K|$ is Hausdorff too.

So let's show that $\eta$ is continuous. For every $\sigma \in S_K$, $\eta \circ inc_\sigma \colon |\sigma| \rightarrow |K|_d$ is an isometry, therefore continuous. The (so called) universal property of the final topology imply $\eta$ is continuous.